# Unix timestamp in Clojure

Tags: unix, datetime, clojure, timestamp

I need to pass in two unix timestamps into a query to pull back data between two dates.

if the script is run today, the 17th of September and needs to get the data for the previous day, the unix timestamps will need to be 00:00:00 of the 16th to 00:00:00 of the 17th.

these timestamps will need to be automatically stored in variables dateFrom and dateTo, so that they can be passed into the query.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time):

```
(require '(clj-time [core :as time] [coerce :as tc]))

;; not timezone-aware
(time/today)
;= #<LocalDate 2013-09-17>

;; UTC
(time/today-at-midnight)
;= #<DateMidnight 2013-09-17T00:00:00.000Z>

;; timestamp at midnight
(tc/to-long (time/today))
;= 1379376000000

(tc/minus (time/today-at-midnight) (time/days 1))
;= #<DateMidnight 2013-09-16T00:00:00.000Z>
```

And so forth.

If you need to convert to `java.sql.Timestamp` rather than `long`, there's `clj-time.coerce/to-sql-time` for that (`java.sql.Timestamp`s are printed using `#inst` literals in Clojure 1.5.1):

```
(tc/to-sql-time (time/today))
;= #inst "2013-09-17T00:00:00.000000000-00:00"
```